# Having problems with counter if i add an else in a nested if statement

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

if I try to put an else after exit while my counter doesn't work, I can find the first name but not the rest. I want to put the else to show a message box if the user has inputted a wrong name. i have tried putting else but if i search for eg the last name it doesn't work because the counter doesn't increments. please can you'll help me with the code without changing the loops.

```
    Dim name(5) As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim search As String

    name(0) = "John"
    name(1) = "Ken"
    name(2) = "Jen"
    name(3) = "Fam"
    name(4) = "Denny"

    search = InputBox("search name")
    found = False
    Dim counter As Integer = -1
    While found = False
        counter = counter + 1
        If search = name(counter) Then
            MsgBox("hello")
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: There is no `Else` statement there to help with.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: For VB.NET it should be Dim name(4) As String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would recommend to use the `For Each` statement, since you are looping through a collection where you need the identifier. So instead of creating a seperate counter, just use the `For Each` identifier.

```
Dim name(4) As String

name(0) = "John"
name(1) = "Ken"
name(2) = "Jen"
name(3) = "Fam"
name(4) = "Denny"

Dim search = InputBox("search name")
Dim index As Integer = -1

For i = 0 To name.Length - 1
    If name(i) = search Then
        index  = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If index > -1 Then
    MsgBox("Name '" + name(index) + "' was found.")
Else
    MsgBox("Name '" + search + "' was not found.")
End If
```

Just to give you an example I've removed the `found` boolean and used the found `index` (or object) instead. In case you want to lookup the object instead of just detecting if the name exists.

An alternative would be to use Linq (Imports System.Linq):

```
Dim found = name.Any(Function(n) n.Equals(search, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use th `found` boolean flag to tell you whether or not the name was found.You set it to true within the if statement and then check for its value after the loop ends. You also would need to exit the while loop after the counter reaches the last element in the list.

```
Dim name(5) As String
Dim found As Boolean
Dim search As String

name(0) = "John"
name(1) = "Ken"
name(2) = "Jen"
name(3) = "Fam"
name(4) = "Denny"

search = InputBox("search name")
found = False
Dim counter As Integer = -1
While found = False
    counter = counter + 1
    If search = name(counter) Then
        MsgBox("hello")
        found = True
        Exit While
    End If
    If Counter = name.Length - 1
        Exit While
    End If
End While

If found = True Then
    MsgBox("Name was found")
Else
    MsgBox("Name was not found")
End If
```

Comment: Yes true the `Exit While` is redundant in this case.But we do need the `found` variable to know if it was the search was located after leaving the loop, correct ?

Comment: I've removed my original comment as it was not correct. You'll need Exit While, but not like this. The loop will stop if the name doesn't exist with an exception: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'. You'll need to test counter and exit the loop after the last item in the array was tested,